# can't get parameter with a value of integer in SQL query

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to get the integer(age information) in my SQL query using this method

```
// ...
Integer age = 42;

String sql = "insert into user_info value('" + username + "','" + passcode + "','" + gender + "',age,'" + email + "')";

try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

finally i got the result of successfully inserting all the information, username, passcode, gender and email, but for the AGE info, it just shows NULL in my mysql database table, and i have tried so hard to fix this but still got confused, please help me out, thx:)

Comment: **[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) alert!!!!** *NEVER* use simple string concatenation to insert user-supplied text into a SQL statement. Use a `PreparedStatement` and statement markers.

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong code, because the `isLogin()` method definitely does not update the database, and doesn't have anything to do with `age`.

Comment: I see your Select query but please add your insert query to your question

Comment: Not relevant title, plz, at first, change the title and then share us your create query and/or any error you've got!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your code first to and then try.

```
gender + "'," + age + ",'" + email
```

Secondly you are not using PreparedStatement in right manner. In PreparedStatement  you set the dynamic values and do concatenate the SQL like this. Check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0):

You got an error in you sql query

```
String sql = "insert into user_info value('" + username + "','" + passcode + "','" + gender + "',age,'" + email + "')";
```

This will not insert the age value, so age will be set to his default value (NULL)

Try with this query

```
String sql = "insert into user_info value('" + username + "','" + passcode + "','" + gender + "','" + age + "','" + email + "')";
```

Comment: @Eric Hoo -  with your query changed , do you still have your problem ?